What is the reason for the unit hypercube domain in the Kolmogorov–Arnold representation theorem?
The descriptions of the Kolmogorov–Arnold representation theorem I've seen (for example, that of Wikipedia) confine the domain of the function in question to be $[0,1]^n$. I'm not quite understanding where this restriction is coming from.
Given that the initial univariate functions $\phi_{q,p} \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ are somewhat flexible in their specification, I'm not sure that you would lose any expressibility if the domain was allowed to be $\mathbb R$. (You could include an implicit $\mathbb R \to [0,1]$ transformation in the function before proceeding with the proof as before.) It seems to me that the theorem would be more generalized in that case, unless there's some edge case with $\pm \infty$ I'm missing.
Or do I have things backwards, and confining the function inputs to be in $[0,1]^n$ is actually a stronger proof than allowing them to be in $\mathbb R^n$?
